# Use Perl like awk to cut fields

Tags: perl

I am new to perl and am attempting to extract data from a file like I would with awk. I have gathered the data from the file and stored it in the array "array". I want to grab the only certain columns and only certain rows. For example, I want to only select the index of 7 (Q) and select the three numbers to eventually make a subroutine to average them out. I also want to be able to grab just a single field from say D for the date. There are very easy ways to do this with awk and cut, but I am having a very difficult time figuring out how to do this with Perl.

```
Here is the data.txt file
F gge0001x gge0001y gge0001z
D 12-30-2006 12-30-2006 12-30-2006
T 14:15:20 14:15:55 14:16:27
S a69 a69 a69
B 15.8 16.1 15
M gge06001 gge06001 gge06001
P 30.1 29.6 29.9
Q 20.2 22.3 23.4
```

I can get it to where I can select the index that I want, I just cant cut the fields

```
Performance Data
Q 20.2 22.4. 23.4
```

Here is my code so far...

```
use constant;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $my_file = 'data.txt';
my @array;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt'
        or die "Cant open : ";

printf ("%10s", "Performance Data\n");

while(<$fh>)
{

        if( /\bF|T|B|P|Q|R|H|O|C|K|W|L\b/)
        {
                push @array, $_;

        }
}


my @tab = split(/\s+/, $array[2]);
print $tab[-2], [-3],  "\n";
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me. You just want to pick the `20.2`, `22.4`, `23.4` from the line that starts with `Q`? Is that right? Or do you want to pick other lines/values as well? /// Do all your lines contain 4 space-separated columns?

Comment: @PerlDuck yes all lines contain 4 space-separated columns. I do wan to just pick 20.2, 20.4 and 23.4 from the Q row. I do also want to pick other rows as well. For instance row F, I just want the second field ( gge0001x). There are other rows with different criteria, but once I figure out how to do it on one example, I should be able to implement it throughout

Comment: A suggestion: when learning a new tool try not to emulate other tools that you know.  While this can help a little bit to get you going, the sooner you get to use the new tool with its native ways and idioms the better.  For instance, there is no need for reference to `awk` and `cut` here.

Comment: `/\bF|T|B|P|Q|R|H|O|C|K|W|L\b/` matches  `\bF` or `T` or `B` or ... or `L\b`.  You probably meant `/\b(?:F|T|B|P|Q|R|H|O|C|K|W|L)\b/` or `/^(?:F|T|B|P|Q|R|H|O|C|K|W|L)/` (which could also be written `/\b[FTBPQRHOCKWL]\b/` or `/^[FTBPQRHOCKWL]/`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to split each line at space characters and then put them into a hash with the first column as key and the remaining 3 columns as value (in an array ref):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# hash which gets filled with { 'Q' => [ 20.2, 22.3, 23.4 ], ... }
my %data;

while( <DATA> ) {
    my @col = split(' ', $_ );
    $data{ $col[0] } = [ $col[1], $col[2], $col[3] ];
}

print Data::Dumper::Dumper(\%data);

__DATA__
F gge0001x gge0001y gge0001z
D 12-30-2006 12-30-2006 12-30-2006
T 14:15:20 14:15:55 14:16:27
S a69 a69 a69
B 15.8 16.1 15
M gge06001 gge06001 gge06001
P 30.1 29.6 29.9
Q 20.2 22.3 23.4
```

**Output** (reduced):

```
$VAR2 = {
  'B' => [
    '15.8',
    '16.1',
    '15'
  ],
  'D' => [
    '12-30-2006',
    '12-30-2006',
    '12-30-2006'
  ],
  ...
  'Q' => [
    '20.2',
    '22.3',
    '23.4'
  ],
  ...
};
```

Now you can access the values for `Q` like this:

```
my $first  = $data{'Q'}[0];
my $second = $data{'Q'}[1];
my $third  = $data{'Q'}[2];
```

This assumes that you have only *one* row starting with `Q`.

Comment: Or `my ($first, $second, $third) = @{ $data{Q} };`

Comment: `split ' '` is a special form of split; it doesn't split on space characters, it splits on any (or multiple) whitespace, like `split /\s+/`, except that it also ignores any leading whitespace.  If you actually want to split on space characters, do `split / /`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as oneliner, for example as:

```
perl -lanE 'print "@F[1,2,3]" if $F[0] eq "Q"' < data.txt
```

prints

```
20.2 22.3 23.4
```

for the meaning of the switches see [prelrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Or using script - one pass:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split /\s+/;
    if( $cols[0] eq 'Q' ) {
        say "for Q: @cols[1,2,3]";
    }
}
```

Use it as `perl script.pl < data.txt` (redirection). It prints

```
for Q: 20.2 22.3 23.4
```

If you want load the whole "matrix" beforehand

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
#use Data::Dumper;

my $matrixref;
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    push @$matrixref, [split /\s+/];
}
#say Dumper $matrixref;

for my $lineref (@$matrixref) {
    if( $lineref->[0] eq 'Q' ) {
        say "for Q: @$lineref[1,2,3]";
    }
}
```

again, using the `perl script.pl < data.txt` prints:

```
for Q: 20.2 22.3 23.4
```

Of course, you can change the `while(<>)` to `while(<$fh>)` and open the file internally... etc.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you have two separate `while(<$fh>)` loops is part of the problem. That second while loop is never running. I'd try combining the loops as the first step to solving the problem.

Comment: I have removed the second loop and have added a new line that is somewhat working.